# Ruby method returns nil, problem with self reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, typeerror, self-reference

I have defined a method called ccy which takes in a number `num`, determines the currency (an attribute of the parent Record model) and returns the number multiplied by a conversion factor. Self, in this case, refers to a Setting, which has a number of attributes of its own and belongs to Record. The method is defined in the Setting model below:

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record

  def ccy(num)
    self.record.currency == "USD" ? ( num * 1 ) :
    self.record.currency == "GBP" ? ( num * 0.616181 ) :
    self.record.currency == "EUR" ? ( num * 0.70618 ) :
    self.record.currency == "CAD" ? ( num * 0.97415 ) : nil
  end
end
```

This doesn't work, however, because after doing some tests I've discovered that `self.record.currency` is nil. So, when I try to do something like `self.ccy(100)` in a rails application, for example, I get the following error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.*
```

or this, if I'm doing using some sort of operator on the nil element:

```
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

I've looked around online for a bit and I can't seem to figure out exactly how to fix this. Help appreciated!

Comment: Do you know for certain that `self` is returning `nil`. Or is it the `record` method returning `nil`. If you do `Setting.new`, `record` is going to be unassigned. However, if you call `my_record.settings.build`, the `record` is pre-populated. (Assuming a `record` `has_many :settings`)

Comment: I know that the record is not nil, and I never do Setting.new. I have my models set up such that creating a new Record creates a new settings object, and accepts nested attributes.

Comment: I know `self.record.currency` is nil because when I add `self.record.currency == "" ? 5` the method returns 5.

Comment: You should use a `case` expression instead of a bunch of nested tertiary expressions.

Comment: OK, I guess I was a little confused as the title reads like `self` was `nil`. On rereading I notice that you do state that `self.record.currency` is what is actually `nil`.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you add `self.record.currency == "" ? 5` and it returns `5`, then I think you actually have an empty string (which is not `nil`)

Comment: A kitten dies every time you use a ternary. I don't like kittens so I use them everywhere now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @monocle's excellent refactoring suggestion:

You might want to make sure that when you're saving the Record, there's a default currency value set.

Something like:

```
  validates_presence_of :currency
  before_save :default_currency
  def default_currency
     self.currency = "GBP" unless self.currency.present? #Woo Anglophilia!
  end
```

You might also have a/n (potentially implicit) `:include_blank => true` in your currency selector such that you're getting these empty values stored in the db.

Comment: You might also look into the Money gem, and ActiveRecord's composed_of association, which are basically specifically designed to handle these sorts of issues.

Comment: All set — what I had to do was fix a problem with my default value settings in my other model that was controlling the currency. I just need to add validations and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have a scope problem? In

```
def ccy(num)
  self ...
```

The self there is referring to an instance of Setting (@setting).

It also seems that this method should be in your Record model. Also, you might consider using a hash for your conversion:

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record
  delegate :convert_currecy, :to => :record
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base

 CURRENCY_CONVERSION_FACTOR =
  {
    "USD" => 1,
    "GBP" => 0.616181
  }

  def convert_currency(num)
    CURRENCY_CONVERSION_FACTOR[currency] * num
  end
```

Comment: Using a hash instead of copious tertiary expressions is definitely much nicer. Thanks!